# iOS bar button higher resolution images?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

The uibarbuttonitem has an image size of ~15x15, however when creating images of that size, they are somewhat pixilated compared to the default images (add/search). I am using photoshop to create these, and saving as a PNG format. Is there a way to get these images as detailed as the default ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create 30x30 versions too, and call them filename@2x.png. There are the retina-specific versions of the images.